# Popup on editing selective textboxes possible?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

I have an issue with a popup in Asp.net using AJAX. Is it possible to show one kind of popup when
the user edits few textboxes and the other kind of popup for the remaining textboxes.

I guess it is possible with some javascript function. Couls someone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: by popup do you mean alert or a dom element?

Comment: i think its neither of them. It is Ajax modalpopupextender.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply add the following javascript onfocus of the textboxes' which need popup1

```
$find('modalpopup1').show();
```

and  analogous on the other textboxus' onfocus which need popup2 to show

```
$find('modalpopup2').show();
```